# R warnings/errors in a fresh install

Tags: r, macos, installation

I just did a fresh reinstall of R 4.2.2 on my mac (macOS 13.1).
It went without glitches, but when I open an R terminal I am getting a lot of warnings? or errors? in red. How can I fix it? (Frankly I started getting these messages with the previous version of R, so that's why I reinstalled it.)

```
1   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff8224306f6 _ZN15MenuBarInstance22EnsureAutoShowObserverEv + 102
2   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff822430288 _ZN15MenuBarInstance14EnableAutoShowEv + 52
3   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff8223d4848 SetMenuBarObscured + 408
4   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff8223d440a _ZN13HIApplication15HandleActivatedEP14OpaqueEventRefhP15OpaqueWindowPtrh + 164
5   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff8223ce8d6 _ZN13HIApplication13EventObserverEjP14OpaqueEventRefPv + 252
6   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff822396af2 _NotifyEventLoopObservers + 153
7   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff8223ce326 AcquireEventFromQueue + 494
8   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff8223bd32c ReceiveNextEventCommon + 285
9   HIToolbox                           0x00007ff8223bd1f3 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
10  AppKit                              0x00007ff81bbc2f63 _DPSNextEvent + 909
11  AppKit                              0x00007ff81bbc1de4 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1219
12  R                                   0x0000000105545998 -[RController doProcessEvents:] + 344
13  R                                   0x00000001055491d9 Re_ProcessEvents + 185
14  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105cebf61 R_ProcessEvents + 33
15  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b8ad0d R_CheckUserInterrupt + 77
16  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b938c4 Rf_eval + 68
17  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bff185 R_LookupMethod + 485
18  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bff93e Rf_usemethod + 254
19  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bbdae6 tryDispatch + 374
20  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105ba5442 bcEval + 70562
21  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
22  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb1d3c forcePromise + 172
23  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a8a Rf_eval + 522
24  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b99533 bcEval + 21651
25  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
26  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
27  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
28  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
29  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
30  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
31  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
32  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb44f4 R_forceAndCall + 868
33  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105af1626 do_lapply + 1094
34  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bfdbfa do_internal + 362
35  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9b20d bcEval + 29037
36  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
37  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
38  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
39  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
40  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
41  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
42  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
43  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb44f4 R_forceAndCall + 868
44  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105af1626 do_lapply + 1094
45  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bfdbfa do_internal + 362
46  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9b20d bcEval + 29037
47  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
48  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
49  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
50  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
51  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
52  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
53  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
54  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
55  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
56  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
57  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
58  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
59  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
60  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb1d3c forcePromise + 172
61  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bbd34a getvar + 778
62  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b97b67 bcEval + 15047
63  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
64  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb1d3c forcePromise + 172
65  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bbd34a getvar + 778
66  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b97b67 bcEval + 15047
67  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
68  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb1d3c forcePromise + 172
69  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bbd34a getvar + 778
70  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b97b67 bcEval + 15047
71  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
72  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb1d3c forcePromise + 172
73  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bbd34a getvar + 778
74  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b97b67 bcEval + 15047
75  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
76  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
77  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
78  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
79  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
80  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
81  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
82  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
83  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
84  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
85  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
86  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
87  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
88  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
89  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
90  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
91  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
92  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
93  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
94  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
95  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
96  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb1d3c forcePromise + 172
97  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bbd34a getvar + 778
98  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b97b67 bcEval + 15047
99  libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
100 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb1d3c forcePromise + 172
101 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bbd34a getvar + 778
102 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b97b67 bcEval + 15047
103 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
104 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb1d3c forcePromise + 172
105 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bbd34a getvar + 778
106 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b97b67 bcEval + 15047
107 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
108 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb1d3c forcePromise + 172
109 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bbd34a getvar + 778
110 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b97b67 bcEval + 15047
111 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
112 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
113 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
114 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
115 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
116 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
117 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
118 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
119 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
120 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
121 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
122 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
123 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
124 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
125 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
126 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b9a92e bcEval + 26766
127 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105b93a01 Rf_eval + 385
128 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb3839 R_execClosure + 2169
129 libR.dylib                          0x0000000105bb2627 Rf_applyClosure + 471
130 libR.dylib                          0x000000010[R.app GUI 1.79 (8160) x86_64-apple-darwin17.0]

[Workspace restored from /Users/asikora/.RData]
[History restored from /Users/asikora/.Rapp.history]
```

then there are more lines of errors/warnings but SE does not let me post them all.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is happening when automatically hiding or showing the menubar is enabled. Note the call to SetMenuBarObscured in the 3rd entry in the stacktrace.  I encountered this problem with emacs after upgrading to MacOS 13.1 as well.
My workaround is to change only automatically hiding the menu bar when in full screen mode since I don't run emacs that way. Or change to never hide the menubar.
SystemSettings => Desktop & Dock => Menu Bar

Comment: I've had the same issue and your workaround worked for me. Now MacOS 13.2 is released. I've set the Menu Bar from "Never" back to "In Full Screen Only" and the errors are gone. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

It's already been answered, but there's an alternative.

For those who always hide the menu bar to reduce clutter and don't use full screen mode, you can set a filter in VSC.

[image]